# How to plot outliers in time series

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, subplot

Matplotlib never finishes when I plot time series outliers. Is my dataset too large or is my code incorrect?

I've played around with some outlier detection with my time series-data and now I'm trying to plot these outliers using a scatter plot on top of a line diagram of my time series data.

However, when I run the code below, the kernel keeps running without result until I'm forced to interrupt it. My data consists of roughly 140,000 time series data points and I have around 2,800 outliers.

Snippet of data:

```
index     Time Series     Outlier

2018-09-01 00:57:00     28.53     0 

2018-09-01 00:58:00     28.49     0 

2018-09-01 00:59:00     28.46     0
```

Code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (36,36))

OL = df.loc[df["Outlier"] == 1, ["Time Series"]]

ax.plot(df["Time Series"], color='blue')
ax.scatter(OL.index,OL["Time Series"], color='red')

plt.show()
```

The expected output should be similar to the below graph.

[image: outlier graph]

Should I change the backend? Or reduce the dataset?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How much RAM do you have? Does it show it as full? Just to check, in the beginning shorten your data set to 1,000 data points with `df = df.iloc[:1000]`

Comment: 16GB, and no. Even if I shorten it down to only 1,000 rows, it still never finishes.

Comment: The code works for me but I'm not using string date format for my index and time series. Can you post a snippet of your dataframe as a dict so that I can load it into pandas correctly? Also, try running the code line by line in ipython to ensure that it is in fact the OL plot that it hangs on.

Comment: Sorry, cant share anything from the dataframe. But it seems to run fine until the "plt.show" line. Idk, why it runs fine for you but not for me. I recently installed pyod, could that have something to do with the issue?

Comment: It's hard to figure out the issue. You can try changing the index to just be a range from 0 to 1000 to match your shortened dataframe and `import numpy as np` then set `df.index=np.arange(0, 1000)`